# Powermock and Mockito. Avoid static initialization for a class while mocking and stubing the same class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Suppose I have a class named Util with static fields:

```
public class Util {

    public static field = Param.getValue("param1");                 

}
```

and the class Param look like this:

```
public class Param {

    public static field = SomeClass.getValue("someValue");

}
```

I want to mock and stubb Param.getValue("param1") inside Util, but at the same time I want suppress static initialization for Param class. How can I achieve this?

This is my first attempt but it's not working

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Param.class})
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("py.com.company.Param")
public class Test {

     @Test
     public void testSomeMethod() {
         PowerMockito.mockStatic(Param.class);
         when(Param.getValue("value1")).thenReturn("someValue1");
     }

}
```

Comment: You probably should refactor this code

Comment: could you explain it?

Comment: As soon as the runtime hits your "Param.class" statement, it will load the class, which will do the static initialization.

Comment: yeah, but how can I refactor this? I can not modify Util and Param classes

Comment: "I can not modify Util and Param classes" refactoring is modifying.

Comment: If you can't modify them, then why do you care about testing their internals?

Comment: @RC.  I thought you were talking about refactoring my test class

Comment: @SkinnyJ I want to test a public method inside Util that uses Param.getValue("param1"), so I want to mock and stub it.

Comment: Why are you testing the internals of `Util` if you can't modify it?

Comment: The way your code is now, you'll have very little control over when that static initialization step happens, so you'll be in a very hard place to modify Param's behavior ahead of that initialization.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me. I get no output, and `SomeClass#getValue` if no `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor({"so35047166.Param"})
@PrepareForTest({Param.class})
public class UtilTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Param.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        final Util util = new Util();
        assertEquals("Util#foo", util.foo());
        assertEquals(null, Util.field);
    }
}
```

with:

```
// all in package so35047166;

public class Util {

    public static String field = Param.getValue("param1");

    public String foo() {
        return "Util#foo";
    }
}

public class Param {

    public static String field = SomeClass.getValue("someValue");

    public static String getValue(final String in) {
        System.out.println("Param#getValue");
        return "Param#getValue";
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public static String getValue(final String in) {
        System.out.println("SomeClass#getValue");
        return "SomeClass#getValue";
    }
}
```