# How to suppress execution of class initializers

Tags: java, reflection

I need to call a bunch of Class.forName() s on third-party classes but this causes the static initializers to run of all the affected classes. This running of the static initializers is a undesired side effect that I want to avoid because the logic pulls in all sorts of other dependencies and other garbage.

Is there a way to prevent these from running? I need the class object, not just info I can get by hacking the class binaries.

I am aware that classes need to be properly initialized before methods should be invoked. I am not doing anything with the code of these classes, I want them  frozen.

Comment: Do you need the Class object or just like the information that the class exists?

Comment: What do you need to do with the `Class` instance? Unless this is something "very meta" (such as listing method signatures), you need that class to be initialized. Java certainly won't let you call into any of its code without setting it up "properly".

Comment: If you need to load the classes, you cannot suppress the static initialization unless you go out of your way and write your own VM or modify an existing VM.

Comment: @Turing85 I see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047166/powermock-and-mockito-avoid-static-initialization-for-a-class-while-mocking-and that it seems to be possible using some implementations. I am not using mockito but if mockito can do it I am hopeful there is a standard way I can do it as well

Comment: @Mishax Mockito tempers internally with the class bytecode. So you wouldn't have the real class object in the end. This in turn would boil down to something like this library: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections I'd assume it would be easier to just use the library then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dependent on the real class containing everything the class consists of, you are stuck with the static initializers unless you patch your virtual machine.

If you just need class meta-information (e.g. method names of the class, implemented interfaces) you can go with a library like [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Your suggestion to use [Powermock/Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047166/powermock-and-mockito-avoid-static-initialization-for-a-class-while-mocking-and) to suppress the static initialization would go in a similar direction as the Reflections library. Both Test frameworks change the bytecode of classes before loading, resulting in slightly different classes than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any additional libraries, you can just do:

```
Class.forName(className, false, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Where the second argument is `initialize` , to flag whether you want the class initialising.

> The class is initialized only if the initialize parameter is true and if it has not been initialized earlier.

The single argument call to `forName` is just a convenience wrapper:

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to:
> `Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)`

See: [Class.forName documentation (Oracle Java SE7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)