# Mockito: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Ignoring a static field initialization in a class used for one of its method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test my below function

```
public class Utils{

      public static String concatString(String stringToConcat) {

      return stringToConcat + StringTools.getCurrentName();
   }}
```

The class StringTools contains indeed the method `getCurrentName()` but it also contains a static field that gets initialized when called

```
public class StringTools{
   private static final int _numberOfDays     = Activator.getNumberOfDays();
   public static getCurrentName(){...}
}
```

Because I am trying to unit tests ONLY `getCurrentName()`, I would like to ignore the initialization of `_numberOfDays`. Is it possible to do ?

I am using Mockito and tried to mock the `StringTools` class but it is throwing this error in my unit test

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: Only way to ignore this is move the static method you want to test into a different class.

Comment: Ok, I thought Mockito or PowerMockito could help for that.

Comment: Hmm maybe it could. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35047166/217324